# Creating a relative symlink in python without using os.chdir()

Tags: python, multithreading, symlink

Say I have a path to a file:

```
/path/to/some/directory/file.ext
```

In python, I'd like to create a symlink in the same directory as the file, that
points to the file.  I'd like to end up with this:

```
/path/to/some/directory/symlink -> file.ext
```

I can do this fairly easily using os.chdir() to cd into the directory and
create the symlinks.  But os.chdir() is not thread safe, so I'd like to avoid
using it.  Assuming that the current working directory of the process is not
the directory with the file (os.getcwd() != '/path/to/some/directory'),
what's the best way to do this?

I guess I could create a busted link in whatever directory I'm in, then
move it to the directory with the file:

```
import os, shutil
os.symlink('file.ext', 'symlink')
shutil.move('symlink', '/path/to/some/directory/.')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Note, I don't want to end up with is this:**

```
/path/to/some/directory/symlink -> /path/to/some/directory/file.ext
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just set the second argument to the destination, like:

```
import os
os.symlink('file.ext', '/path/to/some/directory/symlink')
```

Comment: Just make sure, the link file does not exist, or better, remove it `os.remove("/path/to/some/directory/symlink")`

Answer (score 34):

You can also use `os.path.relpath()` so that you can use symlinks with relative paths. Say your script is in a directory `foo/` and this directory has subdirectories `src/` and `dst/`, and you want to create relative symlinks in `dst/` to point to the files in `src/`. To do so, you can do:

```
import os
from glob import glob
for src_path in glob('src/*'):
    os.symlink(
        os.path.relpath(
            src_path,
            'dst/'
        ),
        os.path.join('dst', os.path.basename(src_path))
    )
```

Listing the contents of `dst/` then shows:

```
1.txt -> ../src/1.txt
2.txt -> ../src/2.txt
```

Relative symlinks are useful for if you want to create a tarball of the whole `foo` directory tree, as I don't believe `tar` updates symlinks to point to the relative path inside of the generated tarball.

Comment: just a warning: your solution looks good and it impresed me.  I tried to apply it in a slightly different situation. `relpath` seems -- according to other discussions -- not very general.  the python relpath function is working properly only for directories, applied to full filepath it does not always produce the expected results (I observe typically that it includes `/../..` when only `/..` is requred.

Comment: @user855443 Had this same problem. The second argument is `start`, which should be the directory (not the file) the path is relative to `os.path.relpath`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, this can be accomplished using *pathlib*

```
from pathlib import Path
target = Path('../target.txt')
my_symlink = Path('symlink.txt')
my_symlink.symlink_to(target)
```

where `target` is a relative `Path` or `str`.

Answer (score 0):

python function to create a relative symlink:

```py
import os

def relative_symlink(src, dst):
    dir = os.path.dirname(dst)
    src = os.path.relpath(src, dir)
    return os.symlink(src, dst)
```

test

```py
os.makedirs("/tmp/srcdir", exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs("/tmp/dstdir", exist_ok=True)
with open("/tmp/srcdir/srcfile", "w") as f:
    f.write("ok\n")
relative_symlink("/tmp/srcdir/srcfile", "/tmp/dstdir/dstfile")
assert os.readlink("/tmp/dstdir/dstfile") == "../srcdir/srcfile"
with open("/tmp/dstdir/dstfile") as f:
    assert f.read() == "ok\n"
os.unlink("/tmp/dstdir/dstfile")
os.rmdir("/tmp/dstdir")
os.unlink("/tmp/srcdir/srcfile")
os.rmdir("/tmp/srcdir")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather `Dst = os.path.join(dir, os.path.basename(dst))`? Otherwise the file is symlinking to itself.

Comment: So, effectively, `Dst` is not necessary, as it's equivalent to `dst`